# Can't run Azure WebJob ManualTrigger attached to Azure WebSite

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017

I have created an Azure WebSite in Visual Studio.  I then added a Azure WebJobs project through Visual Studio.  I then provided the connection string to my storage account to both the app.config file of my WebJob project and the web.config file of my WebSite project.

I still cannot get the job to complete successfully.  It keeps failing, as I can see that on the Dashboard.  When I go to the Dashboard, not only do I see the job failing every time I run it, I also get a red notification that my connection string is incorrect for the AzureWebJobsDashboard.  I've provided this connection string in both projects, and I've copied from the Azure Portal, so there is no way I'm getting the connection string wrong.

How can I fix this?  I'd like to start creating real WebJobs, but I can't even get the example one to work (the one given to you as a ManualTrigger when you add a WebJob project in Visual Studio).

## update

I had forgot to mention that this connection string is also in my application settings in the azure portal already and I still see failures.

Comment: Can you share your webjob code? and what exactly is your web job trying to do and how do you know its failing? (The red connection string message doesn't mean your webjob failed in doing what it was supposed to do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the connection strings on the **Application Settings** page of your WebApp in azure.

**UPDATE**

Use a General-purpose storage account to get rid of 
*System.InvalidOperationException* exception.

Comment: @JakeSmith Can you provide the log output of failing job?

Comment: Where can I find the log output?

Comment: On the Dashboard, where you see the list of executions for the webjob along with their status, click on the last failed execution to see more details. On the details page of the execution there should be a **Toggle Output** button at the bottom along with any exceptions that occured during execution.

Comment: Well, I don&#39;t know how I missed it before but there was the toggle button you speak of. I clicked it and here is the error: `Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Storage account &#39;<name>&#39; is of unsupported type &#39;Premium&#39;. Supported types are &#39;GeneralPurpose&#39;`

Comment: I guess you found the cause. Try using a general purpose storage account.

Comment: Thank you, this was indeed the problem.  I don't understand why Premium is not supported, but I went ahead and just added another storage account with GeneralPurpose performance.  First successful job after those changes were made.  If you want to add this to your answer, I'll accept it!